# How cna I parse an XML string and retrieve specific nodes?

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I have this variable **decodedRequest** as string which has a value of the XML below. I assume I still need to convert this string into XML format. And how can I get the values inside the <request_id> and <response_id> tags, and also the <response_message> tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponseWPF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <application>
      <merchantid>0000011111</merchantid>
      <request_id>456789</request_id>
      <response_id>ASD123</response_id>
      <timestamp>2020-09-23T16:51:47.000000+08:00</timestamp>
      <rebill_id />
      <signature>a246521e3a97bc80502322513434c24d475c4966fe8931b45</signature>
      <ptype>CC</ptype>
   </application>
   <responseStatus>
      <response_code>GR00</response_code>
      <response_message>Successful</response_message>
      <response_advise>Approved</response_advise>
      <processor_response_id>30000</processor_response_id>
      <processor_response_authcode>50001</processor_response_authcode>
   </responseStatus>
   <sub_data />
   <transactionHistory>
      <transaction />
   </transactionHistory>
</ServiceResponseWPF>
```

Comment: Dim xmlString = "<Book id=""bk102"">" & vbCrLf & 
                "  <Author>Garcia, Debra</Author>" & vbCrLf & 
                "  <Title>Writing Code</Title>" & vbCrLf & 
                "  <Price>5.95</Price>" & vbCrLf & 
                "</Book>"
Dim xmlElem = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
Console.WriteLine(xmlElem) look at https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/how-to-load-xml-from-a-file-string-or-stream

Comment: @alessandro how do i get the values inside specific tags?

Comment: you have just to read the docs breaker ;)

Comment: @alessandro where is that? i still cannot get the values :(

Comment: @CodeBreaker If you look at the English version of the docs which alessandro linked to: [How to: Load XML from a File, String, or Stream (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/how-to-load-xml-from-a-file-string-or-stream) then in the left pane you will see an "Accessing XML" section. You should practise your googling skills ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton got it. thanks. It wasn't english so i had hard time looking for it hehe

Answer (score 0):

So this works:

```
    Dim x As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    x.LoadXml(decodedRequest)

Dim req_id As String = x.SelectSingleNode("/ServiceResponseWPF/application/request_id").InnerText

Dim res_code As String = x.SelectSingleNode("/ServiceResponseWPF/responseStatus/response_code").InnerText
```

Comment: In other words, just load the XML string, you don't need to convert it. The question is still unclear - if you asked `how can I parse an XML string and retrieve specific nodes` people would point to duplicates that show how to use either XmlDocument or LINQ to XML.